# NU1101 erratically on MS Hosted windows agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have been erratically getting NU110 erros in our Azure DevOps pipeline for the MS hosted Windows  (vs2017-win2016) based agents. This is been going on for a few days now

```
error NU1101: Unable to find package CommandLineParser. No packages exist with this id in source(s):
```

Is this some kind of a known issue and is there anything required from our end for addressing this?

Thanks

Comment: I have verified and there is no ongoing Azure DevOps incident active in this period https://status.dev.azure.com/_history

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT: I am afraid this does not help. Our builds went fine over this previous weekend, but failed a couple of times yesterday. The issue is very intermittent and I fail to understand why

Comment: Does the pipeline work fine now? Or it still has the same issue.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT: Now it built fine. I don't know for sure if I will face the issue during the day. I will update here if I run into issue again today

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT: We got the problem once again today morning 3 AM IST build

Comment: Not sure the root cause of this issue. Which task are you using? `Dotnet  Build/Restore task` or `Nuget Restore task`. I used the Nuget Restore task and it could work fine. In addition，what package source are you using(Nuget.org or Private package)? Here is a ticket about the [dotnet task](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/983843/dotnet-build-task-does-not-use-nugetorg-for-one-pr.html). It seems that this task has some issues

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT: we are using dotnet restore command. All our packages including CommandLineParser are from nuget.org

Comment: If possible, you could try to use the Nuget Restore task(Similar to the settings in the answer) and check if it could work. This task has the same function as Dotnet Restore task. It seems that the dotnet restore task has some issues itself. Some customers also mentioned this in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/1063175/view.html).

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT: Yes, this works reliably for now. Thanks a lot for your help. Please consider putting this as an answer so that I can accept it and it can help others too until we have a more permanent fix

Comment: Glad to know that the information is helpful. I have updated the answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error NU1101: Unable to find package CommandLineParser. No packages exist with this id in source(s):

As far as I know, the `CommandLineParser` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/) exists in the `nuget.org`.

Here are two methods, you could refer to them.

1. When you use the feeds in `Nuget Restore task`. You could select the `Use packages from NuGet.org`.

[image: Nuget Restore task]

2. When you use the `Nuget.config` file to restore the package, you could add the `Nuget.org` as the package source.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!-- remove any machine-wide sources with <clear/> -->
    <clear />
    <!-- get packages from the NuGet Gallery -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Based on my test, the package could be found successfully.

[image: Restore Result]

**Updates:**

Now the "Dotnet Restore" task has some issues itself. It sometimes causes the  `Unable to find package` issue. For more information, you could refer to [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/983843/dotnet-build-task-does-not-use-nugetorg-for-one-pr.html?childToView=1063175#comment-1063175).

**Workaround:**

You could change to use the `Nuget Restore` task. This task has the same function and it could work fine.